# How to convert a jsp file into excel file in .xlsx format

Tags: java, excel, jsp, xlsx

We are using page content type as below. The excel file(.xlsx format) generates correctly from the application. But not able to open it. While opening it's giving a blank page.

```
<%@ page contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %>
```

Here is the sample structure of my code.

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<HTML xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">

<%@ page contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %>
 <xml>
   <x:ExcelWorkbook>
    <x:ExcelWorksheets>
     <x:ExcelWorksheet>

      <x:Name>Sample Table Structure</x:Name>

      <x:WorksheetOptions>
       <x:Print>
        <x:ValidPrinterInfo/>
        <x:Gridlines/>
       </x:Print>
      </x:WorksheetOptions>
     </x:ExcelWorksheet>
    </x:ExcelWorksheets>
   </x:ExcelWorkbook>
  </xml>
 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>  
</html>
```

Comment: And how do you know it is generated correctly when you are not able to open it?

Comment: I mean to say in the above line was that While generating the excel file the application didn't give any kind of error or exception. And I am able to open it also. But the generated excel was blank.

Comment: OK, two things: 1) it would be useful, if you put more code here, not just the header line of the JSP; 2) actually, you should't use JSP for downloading the file, use servlet;

Answer (score 0):

For Content-Type approach, you might want to set the below line in the directive to cause the entire page to render as Excel.

```
<%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

(OR)

Try `Apache Poi` for export to excel functionality. It is easy to use and we can even format each cell programatically. Otherwise try

```
response.setContentType();
```

Comment: I am already using the page contentType. You can find out in my code. As my requirement is excel in .xlsx format that's why I am using   <%@ page contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" %> here instead of <%@ page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8" %> as it generate a excel file with .xls format.